# ubuntu 22.04 on ASUS expertbook so hot when lid close

Tags: suspend, asus, 22.04

I'm using a laptop name  ASUS Expertbook b1400ceae. it's run ubuntu 22.04. When I close the lid or change the laptop's status to suspend. it will be so hot. The fan not running and when I check the log, I don't see anything running at that time.

Comment: You must have as much swap space as you do RAM in order to suspend. Use `sudo lshw --class memory;free` to aee. First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
`date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp` Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,
`sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"`
  
This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. The first several messages relate to your problem.

Comment: @waltinator yeah I was tried but it still not running anything in that time

Comment: `Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.009 seconds
Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Thg 7 25 19:59:25 whoisltd systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Thg 7 25 20:51:50 whoisltd kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.`